# How to Find memory leaks from native code in android

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Just wondering if someone knows how to find out memory leaks in native code from android. Google search gives lot of solution, but none of them is full. Please let me know if anybody knows how to do this.

Comment: I would see if logcat gives this information

Comment: I get low memory no more background processes; PROCESS DIED

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Really useful information I got to find the leaks in native code.

1. add native=true in ~/.android/ddms.cfg
2. replace `/system/lib/libc.so` with `/system/lib/libc_debug.so`
   restart the framework, start DDMS, you'll see a tab native-heap

In native-heap, you can see the allocations by native code.

For more information [click here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/9c84baa10cebbb68/f6d1e40cac02ffd3?pli=1)

Comment: Also see this article for a step-by-step guide on getting the DDMS native heap tracking setup: http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/2012/04/25/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms/

Comment: Bricolsoft link changed to http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms/