# Native heap not getting updated in DDMS

Tags: android, heap-memory, native, ddms

I use DDMS which is started from the command line using ddms.bat. I am able to bring in the native heap tab by setting the native=1 in ddms.cfg. But the problem is that the native heap is not getting updated. What could be wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find memory leaks from native code in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094242/how-to-find-memory-leaks-from-native-code-in-android)