# Tracking native heap in android using DDMS

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, heap-memory, ddms

I have gone through "http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms" for enabling the native heap tab in DDMS.

I am stuck at getting correct versions of "libc_malloc_debug_leak.so" and "libc_malloc_debug_qemu.so" required to get native heap logs. I followed the instruction at link and extracted the required so files from CyanogenMod ROM that most closely matches your phone’s model and minor Android OS version.

When I place these file in my rooted android phone and try to debug with DDMS, I can see **dlopen** for **libc_malloc_debug_leak.so**  fails saying "**bad ELF magic**". If I am not wrong this must be because I am not using the correct version of these SO files.

Two queries,

1. Is there any way to get the proper versions for these files.
2. Is there any other way to track down native heap in android rather than
   using DDMS?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native heap not getting updated in DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806794/native-heap-not-getting-updated-in-ddms)

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar: the answer to that question links to the site that is linked from this question, so I don't think this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: I think I have got the correct ROM now, because I no longer get "bad ELF magic" error now. But I am stuck now, because ddms logs says <dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "getpagesize" referenced by "libc_malloc_debug_leak.so">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find memory leaks from native code in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094242/how-to-find-memory-leaks-from-native-code-in-android)