# Android debugging C memory leaks

Tags: android, c, memory-leaks, libgdx

I have tried following istrucions [here](http://source.android.com/devices/native-memory.html).
to debug my app because it uses C libraries and C memory allocation (I use libgdx)
it seems to me that I have a leak in my app but the instructions on the link above say you need an eng phone so I rooted an hct one s and then I have found the following instructions I
have found on several websites:

install busybox

```
adb shell
su
```

//beware of the following command as you have to type:

```
mount
```

//first and then check where /system is in the list

//ext4 and /dev/block/mmcblk0p33 may have to be replaced

```
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p33 /system


cp /system/lib/libc.so /system/lib/libc_original.so
```

**cp doesn't work**

```
cat /system/lib/libc.so > /system/lib/libc_original.so
```

**!!beware this breaks phone check if /system/lib/libc_debug.so exists**

```
 adb shell mv /system/lib/libc_debug.so /system/lib/libc.so
```

So luckily after the last command my phone just rebooted and it's working.

Now I have realised, I don't know where to find libc_debug.so, any ideas? phone is htc one s, android 4.1.1. Where are the libs to be found? with source code?

Next question: is i safe to just replace /system/lib/libc.so by /system/lib/libc_debug.so?

Has any body done that, does it even work?

Answer (score 2):

You could try cross-compiling valgrind and using that to debug your memory leaks. Not sure how you are doing your development but, if you checkout AOSP you get valgrind in the external/valgrind and gdb and you can build and drop them onto the device you are trying to debug. Dunno if that might help.

Update: 
Here is a similar approach to what you are doing. They perfomed the steps you did restarted frameworks and then used DDMS to profile for memory leaks, 
[How to Find memory leaks from native code in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094242/how-to-find-memory-leaks-from-native-code-in-android) and a similar post in a google groups [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/APQhE_RLP_s) seems like thats an alternative.

Comment: thanks Quentin, I had a look at valgrind but it seems quite complex and I don't have a nexus S. Do you know of any simpler way? I don't need to debug the C libraries I am using I just would like to see if maybe some of the C objects I create may be leaked. The problem is my app after a while just gets killed. I mean it doesn't crash it just disappears and there are no error logs.

Comment: Updated with some information on ddms looks  like some people generally do what you did set a property on the phone and then use [ddms](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) to try and track down memory leaks. Hope that helps some.

Comment: thks I have done 
% adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 1
% adb shell stop
% adb shell start and it doesn't change the Native tab in ddms is still empty I have htc one s android 4.1.1 rooted. still there a re some logs about allocations that will help me