# How to Find memory leaks from native ndk 'C' code in android (latest way)

Tags: android, memory-management, android-ndk, java-native-interface

What is the way to find memory leaks that are in ndk C code in android studio? As every one on google and stackoverflow refer to ddms for memory leaks in ndk C code but ddms is no longer present in android sdk as described in the following link
[How to Find memory leaks from native code in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094242/how-to-find-memory-leaks-from-native-code-in-android)

It also does not help as there is no way to run ddms.

Comment: I want to find memory leaks in ndk c code

Comment: I think you need to look at AddressSanitizer and Valgrind tools  for getting memory leaks from native ndk C code in android. I am struggling with the same problem here. I was able to run my app using valgrind, but it slows down the application too much. I am currently looking at Address Sanitizer. If you already have the solution can you kindly let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

The description on how to implement that in code is well described in Getting started

Comment: Will this library tell about the memory leaks in c code

Comment: This library does not tell about memory leak in ndk

Comment: You did not mention "Native NDK C code" before editing your post. This is confusing. Before giving any negative vote, know your worth first.

Comment: i have mentioned native code in android and added tags jni and android ndk and also referred a question which is also about ndk

Comment: Now i can not revert that voting

Comment: I don't want you to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Setup [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

Go through the description in Readme to setup.

In your build.gradle:

> dependencies {    debugCompile
>   'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.2'    releaseCompile
>   'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.2'  }

And initialise it in Application class

> ```
> LeakCanary.install(this);
> ```

Comment: Will this library tell about the memory leaks in c code?

Comment: u mean ndk?... This library is configured for the app. So where ever a leak happens within the app it will be shown

Comment: Yes ndk and i want to detect memory leaks in C code

Comment: It should u can refer this Medium Post :- https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/leakcanary-detect-all-memory-leaks-875ff8360745

Comment: There is no description in that library docs that it will catch native ndk memory leaks

Comment: Yes but memory leak is within the app no matter its ndk or native.. so the Leak Canary will be able to capture it

Comment: Unable to build project following error occurs while building 
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/leakcanary/watcher/R;

Comment: This library does not event tell about memory leak in ndk